# Radon-Nikodym Decomposition

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, functional-analysis

Consider $\mathcal{M}([0,1])\equiv C([0,1])^*$ (topological  dual) then the Radon-Nikodym decomposition gives us

$$\mathcal{M}([0,1])=AC([0,1])\oplus \mathcal{S}[0,1]$$

Where $AC([0,1])$ denotes the space of measures that are absolutely continuous  with respect to Lebesgue measure and $\mathcal{S}[0,1]$ are the singular ones.

Show that both spaces in this decomposition are not closed in the weak$^\ast$ topology.

To show that the first is not closed I chose a function $\varphi\geq0$ such that $\int_{0}^{1} \varphi=1$ and defined $\mu_j=j\varphi(x/j)$ for which it is well known that

$$\mu_j\stackrel{*}{\rightharpoonup}\delta_0. $$

For the second part it was a little bit more subtle I first chose $\{q_n\}$ an enumeration of the rationals on $[0,1]$  and let $\Lambda_n=\{q_1,q_2,...,q_n\}$ and defined

$$F_k =\sum_{j=1}^{k}2^{-j}\delta_{r_j}$$

Is there an easy way to prove that this sequence of singular measures  converges Weakly$^\ast$
to

$$F(x)=\sum_{r_n<x}2^{-n}?$$
Notation: $\delta_a(f)=f(a)$

Can anyone indicate a text book where I can find this question and other questions like that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since what seems to be really asked is answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/118467/5363) and [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/90654/about-a-radon-measure-closed)

Comment: The question is different, But I now that decomposition is closed in the strong topology!

Comment: For the second part, your $F_k$ converge *in total variation* (hence also in weak-*) to the measure $\sum_{j=1}^\infty 2^{-j} \delta_{r_j}$, whose distribution function is the $F$ you give.  To see this, note that the total variation of the tail $\sum_{j=k}^\infty 2^{-j} \delta_{r_j}$ is exactly $2^{-k+1}$ which goes to 0 as $k \to \infty$.  But this measure is not absolutely continuous (and the function $F$ is not continuous).  You might instead look at my suggestion [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/118471/822).

Comment: Ok thanks, I see the measure is not absolutely continuous and it cannot be since converges in the strong topology!