# A sequence of singular measures converging weakly* to a continuous measure

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, singular-measures

Can anyone provide a sequence of singular (w.r.t. Lebesgue measure) measures $\in\mathcal{M}([0,1])=C[0,1]^*$ converging $weakly^*$ to an absolutely continuous (w.r.t. Lebesgue measure) measure?

Comment: Two small requests: 1. If you re-post a question, either [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118061/radon-nikodym-decomposition) or [on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/90654/about-a-radon-measure-closed) please say that you asked the same (or a very closely related one) elsewhere. 2. Please don't introduce new tags, stick to those that are available.

Answer (score 7):

$$\mu_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n} \delta_{\frac{i}{n}}$$

Comment: Dear Nate, Pleasingly succinct!  Best wishes,

Comment: +1. [What else](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Ts04dO2RKQ).

Answer (score 2):

If $(x_n)$ is a sequence of points in $[0,1]$, then $x_n$ is [equidistributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution) with respect to the absolutely continuous measure $f(x)dx$ (where $dx$ denotes Lebesgue measure) precisely if the sequence of singular measures $\dfrac{1}{n} \sum_n \delta(x-x_n)$ on $[0,1]$ converges in the weak-$*$ topology to the measure $f(x)dx$.

For example, if $(x_n)$ is the sequence $(\alpha n \bmod 1)$ for an irrational number $\alpha$ then $(x_n)$ is equidistributed with respect to Lebesgue measure $dx$.

Comment: A reference for this  equidistributed sequences besides wikipedia?